# Updating Button's background_color not reflected on the UI sometimes

Tags: kivy

Well, I'm creating a Kivy app in which you can select only one of many statuses. Every status has his own `Button` and the selected status has a different `background_color` from the others.

The problem is that sometimes (apparently random) after clicking a button, two of them stays with his background changed at the same time. The strange thing is that I'm checking the `background_color` of those elements and it doesn't match with the result that I'm seeing on the screen.

So, the `background_color` property has one color but another one is being rendered on the screen.

Relevant kv file section:

```
<StatusButtonsContainer>:
    cols: 2
    spacing: 8
    padding: 0,16,0,0

<StatusButton>:
    selected: False
    text: self.status_name
    on_release: app.on_change_status_click(self.status_name)
    font_size: '16'
    background_color: self.back_color if self.selected else (0.259, 0.259, 0.259,1)
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: ''
    background_disabled_normal: ''
```

This is how I'm creating the `Button` widgets dinamically:

```
class StatusButtonsContainer(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StatusButtonsContainer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for name, color in config.statuses.items():
            button = StatusButton(status_name=name, back_color=color)
            self.add_widget(button)


class StatusButton(Button):
    status_name = StringProperty()
    back_color = ListProperty()
```

And this the function that is executed when the button is pressed:

```
class ControlsScreen(Screen):

    def change_selected_status(self, status):
        for button in self.ids.buttons_container.children:
            if button.status_name == status:
                button.selected = True
                button.disabled = True
                print('Status ' + button.status_name + ' was selected.')
                print('background_color:' + str(button.background_color))
            else:
                button.selected = False
                button.disabled = status in ['printing', 'preparing', 'paused']
                print('Status ' + button.status_name + ' was NOT selected.')
                print('background_color:' + str(button.background_color))
```

It's even more weird that this is happening on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian, but I'm not able to reproduce it on a Windows machine... I double checked that the [input] section in the config is correct and the buttons are being pressed only once.

**Versions**

- Python: 3.6.0
- OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
- Kivy: 1.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was that I was updating the UI in a thread different from the main thread.

In my application, the button status can be changed either from the UI directly or from a web socket message. So, when the button's `background_color` was changed through web socket, the UI update was called by another thread and, for some reason, that was causing the issue.

I've solved it with the `@mainthread` decorator:

```
@mainthread
def change_status_ui(self, status):
    self.get_screen('Controls').change_selected_status(status)
    self.get_screen('Status').change_status(status)
```

Now, it doesn't matter which thread call this method, it will be executed on the main thread.